# Reading unformatted name/value pairs from a file, formatting it, and printing it out in Python 2 dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, io

Given a text file like so

```
# Name_value_pair.txt
name1 = value1
name2 = value2
name3 = "some value3"
name4=value4
name5=
name6
```

Is it possible to read that file, format it into a dictionary and print it out using python?

I know how to open and read the files, but I don't know if its possible to filter out the horrible formatting in order to get it into a form suitable to be made into a dictionary?

edit: It seems that the ConfigParser module would be a better fit for the job I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: What would the dictionary look like for your example text file? name6 doesn't even have an equals sign, so what should the value be?

Comment: the dictionary should only take the 'names' as keys and 'values' as values. name6 would be ignored because it does not have an =, but name5 would be accepted with its value being null.

Comment: split the line on the equal and from there make two lists then zip the lists into a dict and you straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ignore any lines without a '=', then from the remaining lines, remove any quotes and whitespace on the outside of each key and value, then put it into a dict:

```
data = {}

with open('in.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if '=' not in line:
            continue
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        data[(line.split('='))[0].strip()] = (line.split('='))[1].strip()

for k, v in data.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
name1: value1
name2: value2
name3: some value3
name4: value4
name5:
```

Comment: This is very helpful!
Thank you, I'm fairly new to python(started last week) and was not sure where to even start with this.

Comment: You're welcome. If the code works well for you, please mark answer as correct.

Comment: The only issue is that if the key does not have an = it should be ignored but I should be able to do that now.

Comment: I'm going to make an update to use a better form for `open()`, so I'll fix that for you too.